# Javascript canvas, color is not being applied properly

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have the following javascript canvas that draws a bunch of texts in the screen

```
//Draws the prices fonts
    priceList.map((i, index) => {
        ctx.font = "11px Ariel"
        if(index == 0){
            ctx.fillText(i.toFixed(2), ctx.canvas.width - 42, (heightPoints * index) + 9); //This one is being painted in black
        }else{
            ctx.fillText(i.toFixed(2), ctx.canvas.width - 42, (heightPoints * index) - 5);
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
    })
```

The resulting canvas is the following numbers

[image]

As you can see, theres a circled spot, and thats because the font of that number is black, and i cant seem to manage to change its color

It is drawn when index === 0

Why is that happening? Why isnt fillStyle applying for every element?

EDIT: Apparently its being painted but i cant get it down

[image]

UPDATE:
Apparently that last value even tho its being logged, i cant paint it anywhere
Ive tried to paint it in an arbitrary (Center of the screen) place and it wont display

```
priceList.map((i: number, index: number) => {
        ctx.font = "11px Arial"
        if(index === 0){ //nowhere to be found
            ctx.fillText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 500, 500);
            console.log(i) //64854.00000000001
            console.log(ctx.canvas.height) //885
            console.log(ctx.canvas.width) //1157
        }else{
            ctx.fillText(i.toFixed(2), ctx.canvas.width - 46, (heightPoints * index) - 5);
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    })
```

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but your font should be 'Arial'

Comment: How are you confirming that the text is colored black as opposed to simply being wrogly positioned? Have you tried moving `ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";` to the beginning instead of the end, or before the `.map` statement?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I will update with a pic, apparently color is changing but its not coming down, it gets stucks right above the canvas for some reason and i cant lower it anymore

Comment: @mouchin777 _“i cant lower it anymore”_ — Why not? Simply try a different offset in `(heightPoints * index) + 9`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon well its weird i dont know why is it happening. Im also trying to paint it at the top of the screen with ````ctx.fillText(i.toFixed(2), ctx.canvas.width - 46, ctx.canvas.height+10);```` and its not going down

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Again, move the `ctx.fillStyle` to a point _before_ you paint the text.

Comment: @SebastianSimon that was it thanks